# Need to convert a date into target timezone date with DST (daylight savings time)

Tags: python-3.x

I have a datetime in this format "`20200123114953`". I am able to convert the datetime to target timezone datetime as "`2020-01-23T00:19:53-0600`", in this it is *not* respecting daylight saving.

I expect the time with offset value "-5:00", but I get "-6:00" for US/Eastern.

Could someone please help me out with the logic in Python that respects DST?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime as dt
import pendulum
import pytz


def getDateTime(datetime_, is_timezone_required=None, input_format=None, output_format=None, default='False'):
    is_timezone_required = False if is_timezone_required.lower() in ["false"] else True
    timezone = None
    input_format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
    output_format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%Sz"
    timezone = "US/Eastern"

    if is_timezone_required:
        if "%z" not in output_format:
            output_format += "%z"

    else:
        if "%z" in output_format:
            output_format = output_format.replace("%z", "")

    datetime_object = dt.datetime.strptime(datetime_, input_format)
    timezone_py = pytz.timezone(timezone)

    datetime_object = datetime_object.astimezone(timezone_py)

    output = dt.datetime.strftime(datetime_object, output_format)
    return output


getDate = getDateTime('20200123114953', "True")
print(getDate)
```

"This gets an output: 2020-01-23T01:19:53z-0500
My expectation is   : 2020-01-23T02:19:53z-0400"